# Not able to display values in PickerView from a NSMutableArray which gets data from a NSDictionary

Tags: ios

I am not able to display data from a NSMutableArray into a UIPickerView. The NSMutableArray gets its value from a NSDictionary through a function. When I run the code i get

```
'-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization

    }

    return self;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];



    [self setViewElementProperties];

    self.preButton.hidden=YES;

    self.nextButton.hidden =YES;


    if (self.prayerID) {



    }else if (self.prayerItem){

        [self populatePrayerDataFromDictionary];



    }



}//end of ViewDidLoad





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];



}







- (void)setViewElementProperties{

    self.prayerTitleField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

    self.prayerTitleField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];

    self.prayerTitleField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [self.prayerTitleField setEnabled:NO];



    self.prayerTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];

    [self.prayerTextView setEditable:NO];



    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(shareButtonPressed:)];



    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;





}

-(void)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

    self.myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,300,0,0)];

    self.myPickerView.dataSource = self;

    self.myPickerView.delegate =self;

    self.myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    self.myPickerView.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];


    self.pickerViewValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //(pickerview values)

    [self getFamilyAndOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentMember];





    [self.view addSubview:self.myPickerView];

}//end of shareButtonPressed



-(NSMutableArray *)getFamilyAndOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentMember

{

    self.pickerViewValues = [self getOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentAccount];



    NSMutableDictionary *familyAccount = [@{@"ID":@0, @"USERNAME":@"family"} mutableCopy];

    [self.pickerViewValues addObject:familyAccount];



    NSString *shareableMembers = self.pickerViewValues;



    return self.pickerViewValues;

}





-(NSMutableArray *)getOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentAccount{

    NSMutableArray *members = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *accountID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"accountID_efs"];

    NSString *currentMemberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"memberID_efs"];



    NSDictionary *accountIDDict = @{@"ACCOUNT_ID":accountID, @"CURRENT_MEMBER_ID":currentMemberID};

    SQLiteResult *memberTableQueryResult = [SQLiteDatabase qin:@"SELECT ID, USERNAME FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID IN (SELECT MEMBER_ID FROM ACCOUNT_MEMBERS WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = :ACCOUNT_ID AND MEMBER_ID <> :CURRENT_MEMBER_ID) ORDER BY USERNAME" withParams:accountIDDict];



    if (memberTableQueryResult.rows.count) {

        members = [memberTableQueryResult getResultData];

    }



    return members;

}





//UIPIckerView DataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

{

    return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    return [self.pickerViewValues count];
}





// UIPickerView Delegate



-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

  return [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row]; 

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    NSString *selectedPickerValue = [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row];    
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your question properly

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are calling `length` for an `NSDictionary` in your code somewhere. The correct method to get the number of entries in a `NSDictionary` is `count`.

Answer (score 0):

From what i've briefly read through this horribly formatted question, i see two issues.

First, you're giving a newly alloc-inited array as picker values, so it can't be anything else than empty. Second,  i'd say that this line is the problem, in `sharedButtonPress:(id)sender`

```
[self getFamilyAndOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentMember];
```

Please try and put a breakpoint there to see if it crashes there. If it does (which i'm hoping it should), it is because you're returning an `NSMutableArray` (according to the method just under it) to `self`. `self` here is the viewController.

Simply change this line :

```
 self.pickerViewValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

with this line :

```
[self.pickerViewValues = getFamilyAndOtherMemberIDUsernamesOfCurrentMember];
```

And you should both overcome the crash and have values. Now if you have another crash, please do theses things :

- Format your question/code properly, this is really hard to read and make people not want to help you.
- Try and put breakpoints to see the exact line/reason it is failing
- Of course, submit us every piece of information you have about it :)